# Laravel 5.2 : Undefined Variable in WhereHas

Tags: laravel

I get `undefined variable $jenis_mobil` exactly on `$q->where('name', $jenis_mobil->name)`

```
    $jenis_mobil = Car_class::find($request->jenis_mobil);
    $dari_kota = City::find($request->dari_kota);       

    $vehicles = Vehicle::whereHas('car', function($q){
        $q->whereHas('car_class', function($q){
            $q->where('name', $jenis_mobil->name);
        });
    })
    ->whereHas('partner', function($q) {
        $q->whereHas('kota_pool', function($q){
            $q->where('name', $dari_kota->name);
        });
    })
    ->where('year', $request->tahun_mobil)
    ->get();
```

Is something wrong with my code? I think because `$jenis_mobil` not passed to `whereHas`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `use()` to pass variables into the closures:

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::whereHas('car', function($q) use($jenis_mobil) {
    $q->whereHas('car_class', function($q) use($jenis_mobil) {
        $q->where('name', $jenis_mobil->name);
    });
})
->whereHas('partner', function($q) use ($dari_kota) {
    $q->whereHas('kota_pool', function($q) use ($dari_kota) {
        $q->where('name', $dari_kota->name);
    });
})
->where('year', $request->tahun_mobil)
->get();
```